# STL/Boost container like array, storing elements in sorted order, no gaps?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, boost

I'd like to insert and 'delete' elements on a fixed-sized array. After each operation the elements are in sorted order and contiguous (no gaps).

The first element will be inserted in the middle.

Are there any existing containers (including Boost) which do this? I can write some of the logic but surely this must be an uncommon requirement?

I can add some of the additional/non-vanilla logic on top.

Comment: Generally, this sort of structure is very slow to insert and erase, and is almost never needed directly, so I don't think I've ever seen a container for it. Boost might have one though

Comment: [boost::multi_index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) stores elements in sorted order without gaps, but doesn't present them as a contiguous array.

Comment: If you do the sorting yourself, `std::array` and `std::vector` will both store the values "without gaps".

Comment: @JesperJuhl Started to do it myself but now i've got to handle the shifting, maintaining head, tail as inputs for lower_bound etc. Presumed someone must have done this before.

Comment: Note that insertion and deletion will be done in `O(n)` time because of the contiguity. So `O(n²)` for `n` insertions. This is not performant unless you travel the structure (in an ordered way) very often compared to any mutation.

Comment: Are gaps at the end allowed?  For example, with a 10 element capacity data structure, I remove the 3rd element, are the remaining elements moved up by one (to fill the grap from the removal)?  This will leave a gap at the end.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes gaps at the end are perfectly fine. In fact, they are preferred because I'd like to insert the first element from the middle and then go adjacent up/below from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `boost::container::flat_set` and `boost::container::flat_map`.

E.g.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b2a4822b02c374b)**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bc = boost::container;

int main() {
    static const bc::flat_map<std::string_view, int> m{
        {"one", 111}, {"two", 222}, {"five", 555}, {"seven", 777}, {"nine", 999},
    };

    for (auto [k,v]: m) {
        std::cout << quoted(k) << " -> " << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints the expectable

```
"five" -> 555
"nine" -> 999
"one" -> 111
"seven" -> 777
"two" -> 222
```

More interestingly, the iterators are random-access and indeed refer to adjacent indices:

```
auto one = m.find("one");
auto seven = m.find("seven");
for (auto it : {one, seven}) {
    std::cout << "index of " << quoted(it->first) << ": " << (it - m.begin()) << "\n";
}

std::cout << "one and seven are " << (seven - one) << " places apart\n";
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e52d6072a49bb7a)**

```
index of "one": 2
index of "seven": 3
one and seven are 1 places apart
```

### Static/pre-allocation and optimizations

There are optimized constructors/operations to adopt a known-sorted sequence:

```
bc::flat_set<int> m;
m.adopt_sequence_equal(bc::ordered_unique_range, {111,222,555,777,999});
```

You can even have them optimized for fixed/small sizes. E.g. a simple statically sized map with max 10 entries:

```
namespace bc = boost::container;
template <typename K, typename V, typename Cmp = std::less<K>, typename Pair = std::pair<K const, V>>
using Map10 = bc::flat_map<K, V, Cmp, bc::static_vector<Pair, 10>>;

static Map10<std::string_view, int> const m{
    {"one", 111}, {"two", 222}, {"five", 555}, {"seven", 777}, {"nine", 999},
};
```

Still works [the same way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1eaf92f0a9615f5).

This has zero runtime allocations.

Comment: In your example we've fixed the size to 10. Is it possible to add more than 10 and `flat_map` only keep the top 10 by greatest (or smallest) key value? As in, it will discard keys which fall out of the top 10 when sorted. I'm testing and I get a bad_alloc exception when I add more than 10 keys. It makes sense, I just wonder if it's possible to change this.

Comment: Perhaps a priority queue on ring buffer. Of course you can add your application logic in your own code. Make it capacity 11 and resize after each insertion? Also note that static size is rather extreme. You can use regular vector (the default), small_vector (a good midway point that avoids allocating for small size) or potentially other strategies. I haven't tried but using a deque might end up with the growth pattern you describe in the question for some insertion orders. Boost gives you building blocks in which you can realize the datastructure you require. Mine are just examples

Answer (score 2):

I doubt anyone has this particular structure prebuilt. Unless you can guarantee that most insertions happen near the end, performance will be atrocious. But of course this guarantee may exist, for example when iteratively building a sparse matrix.

Anyway, with [`boost::container::devector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.devector) and [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) you have everything you need to make it a one-line function.

```cpp
#include <boost/container/devector.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <random>


template<class T>
void insert(boost::container::devector<T>& vec, const T& val)
{ vec.insert(std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val), val); }

int main()
{
    boost::container::devector<int> vec;
    std::default_random_engine rng;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        insert(vec, static_cast<int>(rng()));
    assert(std::is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end()));
}
```

However, given the poor performance, consider alternatives such as `std::map` or sorting only on first access if the structure is read-mostly.

Comment: As I've just posted, Boost Container has decent utilities in this area. And now that I'm typing this, I just remember that Boost Unordered just added open-addressing implementations that use flat allocation - which is tangentially related. This idea to optimize for storage/iteration efficiency is oft-recurring